# multiple layer smoothed plots using qplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, dplyr, ggvis

here is the sample data-set of the plot that i have tried

```
x<-runif(3, min=4, max=50)
y<-runif(6, min=3, max=14)

x1 <-runif(8, min=7, max=52)
y1 <-runif(5, min=5, max=18)
```

i can plot smooth line using the following code.

```
qplot(y,x, geom='smooth', span =0.05)
qplot(y1, x1, geom='smooth', span =0.05)
```

but they are plotted in two separate plots; how can i plot both the smooth lines on a same plot on different layers?

Comment: something like this? `ggplot()+geom_smooth(aes(x,y))+geom_smooth(aes(x1,y1))`

Comment: The vectors in your example have different lengths. They should be the same size if you want to combine them in `geom_smooth()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some problems with your example as pointed out in the comments

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sort(runif(20, min=4, max=50))
y <- sort(runif(20, min=3, max=14))

x1 <-sort(runif(20, min=7, max=52))
y1 <-sort(runif(20, min=5, max=18))
```

You can use `qplot` and string a bunch of layers together

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x, y) + geom_smooth(aes(x, y)) + geom_point(aes(x1, y1)) + geom_smooth(aes(x1, y1))
```

[image]

But it is easier to use `ggplot` once you have the data in the proper format

```
dd <- data.frame(x, x1, y, y1)
ll <- reshape(dd, dir = 'long', varying = list(1:2, 3:4))

ggplot(ll, aes(x, y, group = time)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth()
```

Comment: hey i plotted successfully ; but is there any way i can remove points and just leave the lines on the plot ?

Comment: @saurabh just remove the points layer `ggplot(ll, aes(x, y, group = time)) + geom_smooth()`